# @qualifier not working with @Component

Tags: java, spring

Hi guys I am using Java based configurations & I have 2 classes like this:

HelloWorld.Java

```
@Component
@Qualifier("hello")
public class HelloWorld {

  public void helloWorld() {
    System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:application-config.xml");

    HelloWorld hw = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("hello"); 
    hw.helloWorld();
  }
}
```

application-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.basepackage" />
```

This gives me the following error: `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'hello' is defined`

Whereas if I use `HelloWorld hw = context.getBean(HelloWorld.class)` it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Qualifier` does not set the name of the bean, it just adds additional metadata to it. However, [`getBean(String)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-) expects the bean name as its argument. You have no beans named `hello`.

The bean's name can be set with

```
@Component("hello")
```

in which case the `@Qualifier` becomes rather useless in this scenario.